# apacheignite/web-console-backend image having an issue "Waiting: CrashLoopBackOff "

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

apacheignite/web-console-backend image having an issue "Waiting: CrashLoopBackOff "error:- enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/web-console/package.json'. Do we have any other image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use previous version of docker image 2.6.0, it should be compatible with Ignite version 2.6 and below.

I've reproduced the issue by using docker-compose and created a ticket in Ignite JIRA for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12007

Comment: Now getting Error to run ignite-cluster.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.

Comment: what I need to put inside this property:-  name: TOKENS value: "" under web-agent-deployment.YAML file

Comment: ERROR:- when I used " web-agent-deployment.YAML " 


[2019-07-24 17:43:42,811][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] You are using an older version of the agent. Please reload agent

Comment: Regarding web-agent, you shouldn't use image from DockerHub, instead of that you should download web-agent from web-console and build docker image by yourself. Generated web-agent archive will contain "default.properties" file with filled TOKENS value. You can find more information regarding this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179602/starting-webagent-on-apache-ignite-for-docker

Answer (score 0):

Try `apacheignite/web-console-backend:2.6.0` if you don't mind using a little bit older version. For me it worked fine. Only `2.7.0` ( currently latest ) seems to have this issue.